# How to generate Material UI stepper dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI for my project and like to generate Stepper component based on a list I get from my API. For simplicity, I tried to get this code working, but get an

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in.

Can somebody help me figure out why this is not working?

Thanks,

```
import React from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { Step, Stepper, StepLabel } from 'material-ui/Stepper';

function getTestStepper() {
    var stepperLabels = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
    var steps = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < stepperLabels.length; i++)  {
        var id = stepperLabels[i] + "_" + i;
        var label = stepperLabels[i];
        var step = (
            <Step key={id}>
                <StepLabel> {label} </StepLabel>
            </Step>
        )
        steps.push(step);
    }
    return (<Stepper activeStep={0}> {steps} </Stepper>)
}


export default class StepperTest extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider> 
               <div>{getTestStepper()}</div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Everything looks correct. Are you sure you have the `material-ui` package installed locally?

Comment: ChaseDeAnda : I installed material-ui with npm, and if I change `<Stepper>` to for example `<List>` (and `<Step>` with `<ListItem>`) this works perfectly, the error occurs when I use the stepper component.....

Comment: Make sure your local copy matches the latest version for material-ui (0.18.3).